# faceletes property bundles how to bold text

Tags: html, jsf-2, internationalization, facelets, bold

I make heavy use properties from bundles in my application as I strive to keep code maintainable in future. Because of this all HTML text is fetched from a key/value properties file eg. 'index_en.properties'

This has become problematic where I need the browser to render **bold** text and I don't find any topics online that address this problem.

Best solution I can then up would be to break every fetched value down with use of the

```
<h:outputText> tags that are child elements of the `<b>` tags.
```

What I need here is a methodology/tips/solution  from someone who uses property files often.

I tried using html escape codes directly in the properties file, but this does not work.

Any tips?

Thank you,
Yucca

PS I doubt CSS will help me here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put HTML `<b>` in bundle and use `escape="false"` on `<h:outputText>` to disable standard HTML escaping by the component:

```
<h:outputText value="#{msg.text}" escape="false" />
```

Be sure that you **never** do this on user-controlled input as it would put XSS attack holes open. Also be sure that you don't go overboard with putting HTML in bundles. For basic text formatting with `<b>`, `<u>`, `<i>`, `<s>` and so on it's okay, but not for semantic markup like `<p>`, `<div>`, `<h1>`, etc.

Comment: @ BalusC Many thanks and thanks again for the security tip. I only fetch content text from bundles, but this is the first time I really needed it. I usually make use of CSS for styling, but like I said this is a whole paragraph being loaded from a resource bundle.

Comment: would it be ok to make an anchor element using this methodology. My site doesn't take any user input, but would be good to know for future reference?